# iMacro is not reacting as expected

Tags: automation, imacros, data-extraction

I'm new to `iMacros`, I tried to develop one, but struck here.

any help or reference will be much appreciated.

I want to go to Google, then type text, and want to get all the stuff that appears in anchor tag(Link and text)

Here what I got so far.

```
VERSION  BUILD=7500718 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:tsf ATTR=ID:lst-ib CONTENT=Blaze
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ID:tsf ATTR=NAME:btnG
TAG Pos=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:r EXTRACT=TXT
```

but if pops up with a box `#EANF#`, I guess some sort of error or warning.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=CITE ATTR=CLASS:"_Rm" EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=H3 ATTR=CLASS:r EXTRACT=TXT
' prompt extracted values or do something else
PROMPT {{!EXTRACT}}
```

Play the above macro in loop mode when you are already on the ‘google’ page which you want to get content of (i.e. after running first five lines of your code).